# Most efficient way to hide all rows in which a certain value occurs

Tags: excel, vba, find

The Excel auto filter is not properly working if there is more than one row for headings, and it is also not assignable to specific columns, only. So I want to filter by VBA macro.

I have

```
Sheet2.Range("A1:A40").Find(what:="Software", _
After:=Cells(4, 1), _
LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False _
).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

But this only hides the row with the first occurance of "Software". Is there no way to use .find for that or do I have to use a loop?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work properly with more than one header row?  If you highlight only the data area and the bottom row and then hit the filter button it will only filter the selected data.

Comment: I would avoid using Find() when hiding rows or columns, since `Find()` *will not locate a cell in a hidden row or column*: that can make your process a little more difficult to manage.  For non-huge ranges @BruceWayne's suggestion should be fine.

Comment: @ Scott Craner: I have to correct myself: Indeed you can put a filter to  columns from the third, fourth or lower row, but only if the head cell is not combined. And you can't put a filter to individual, non adjacent columns. Good, however, that you don't have to select the "bottom row" - who can tell, which one that might be(come)? ;-)
@ Tim Williams: Yes, I know about this, but the demanded purpose is not affected by this limitation. The script will unhide all rows before a subsequent filtering takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your range isn't super big, you can always loop through it, checking for a value, and hiding if found:

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

lastRow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Software" or cells(i,1).Value = "software" Then
     Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: the `software` part is case sensitive, which is why I used `Or`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that script. It is helpful, though I actually want to know, if the Find method can give a selection of all matching results, even if they are non adjacent. This, of course, would make the parameters SearchOrder and SearchDirection expendable.

Comment: Using find, if you wanted to find the cell address of all cells, I would maybe create an array, and then get the cells like `myCellAddress = Cells.Find(What:="software",MatchCase:=False).`.  [Here's an](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba) SO thread that gives a pretty good example.