# How to debug VBA code using .Find and Offset?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm practising VBA and I need some help / correction for my code.
In this task I'm creating a search tool which looks up each worksheet for the selected value from a combobox. Each result is listed on the first page.

Problems:

1. In the code I defined the `.Find` method in to a range `rFound`. On each worksheet the searched value is at column `D`. I would like to copy the row from column `B` to `E`. I've commented an attempt how did I tried to select that range, with offset but I receive an error. Why and how to fix that?
2. When I want to paste (list) the results I want it to start from the 1st page 3rd row column `K`. After running the code it selects the right target but pastes nothing. How to fix this?

I've also made some attempts to copy the document header after each search result, but I commented them out, please ignore lines with `getOwner`.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, OutputWs As Worksheet, wsLists As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range ', getOwner As Range
Dim strName As String
Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim IsValueFound As Boolean
'Dim cboSelectName As ComboBox
Dim a As String


IsValueFound = False
Set OutputWs = Worksheets("Teszt")    '---->change the sheet name as required
LastRow = OutputWs.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set wsLists = Worksheets("Lists")

a = ComboBox1.Value

On Error Resume Next
strName = a
If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Output" Then
        With ws.UsedRange
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto rFound, True
                IsValueFound = True
                'MsgBox rFound.Row
                rFound.EntireRow.Copy
                'Rfound keres - rFound.Range(rFound(Offset(-2,")),rFound.Offset(1,"")).Copy  ' ---> This is a suggestion
                OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 2, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                'getOwner.Range(K2, R2).Copy        ' attempt to copy the header for each search result
                'getOwner.Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                LastRow = LastRow + 1
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0
If IsValueFound Then
   OutputWs.Select
   MsgBox "Search Complete!"
Else
    MsgBox "Value not found"
End If
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are copying where, but copying cells `B:E` of the `rFound`'s row to column `K` of `OutputWs` would be `Application.Intersect(rFound.EntireRow, rFound.Worksheet.Range("B:E")).Copy OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 2, "K")`. Or `rFound.Worksheet.Range(rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B"), rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "E")).Copy OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 2, "K")`. Or `rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, 4).Copy OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 2, "K")`.

Comment: The last one is working
rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, 4).Copy
Unfortunately the search is not... Can you tell why the code does not search for drop-down list values? In my excel sheet I want to list all the names which occurs on each worksheet and these names are selected from a drop-down list. I made an example like 4 same names in each row at sheet 2. And when I run the code it only shows the first result. Why is that?

Comment: All of them are working and do exactly the same.

Comment: Because `Find` finds one match at a time. If you want all matches, you [must repeatedly call `Find`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19504858/11683).

Answer (score 0):

You are selection entire row but you are pasting it to the column K. If you copy entire row, you can only copy it to column A. That's why it is not working. So I suggest you to work on Offset part. 
In Offset, first part is rows, second part is columns.
you can do something like that,

```
Dim sth as Range
set sth = .range(.rfound.offset(0,-2),.rfound.offset(0,1)).copy
```

But I am not sure of it. Not very good at that.