# Changing cell value using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change cell values using an excel macro.

For example, changing this group:

```
Codes:
CareBears
Catpaws
CareBears
Catpaws
CareBears
Doghound
Catpaws
Doghound
```

into:

```
Codes:
Bear
Cat
Bear
Cat
Bear
Dog
Cat
Dog
```

I successfully transformed them automatically using macro recording but when the data switches position or there is an additional row of data, that data is not been read.

I am seeking your assistance regarding on this matter.

Comment: Please provide the code you are currently using.

Comment: And then try for yourself if updating the ranges to the new desired values will solve your problem.

Comment: As per what macro man said, edit your original question and paste in your macro.

Comment: Does this have to be a macro or would a formula suffice?

Comment: Is it always cat, bear and dog substring you care about?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you dont need to replace the values, and you only every have to deal with bears, cats and dogs you could add a formula in column B, if your codes are in column A.  Its not pretty but it works.

Put this in B2, and copy down, with your codes in column A.

> =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Bear",A2,1))),"Bear",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Dog",A2,1))),"Dog",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Cat",A2,1))),"Cat","?")))

I appreciate this doesnt answer the "macro" question.  And dont try and use this if you have values like DogBear ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindAndExecute()
'got the  answer working with this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim Loc1 As Range
    Dim Loc2 As Range

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sh.UsedRange
            Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="Carebears")
            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                Do Until Loc Is Nothing
                    Loc.Value = "Bear"
                    Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
                Loop
            End If

            Set Loc1 = .Cells.Find(What:="Catpaws")
            If Not Loc1 Is Nothing Then
                Do Until Loc1 Is Nothing
                    Loc1.Value = "Cat"
                    Set Loc1 = .FindNext(Loc1)
                Loop
            End If
            Set Loc2 = .Cells.Find(What:="Doghound")
            If Not Loc2 Is Nothing Then
                Do Until Loc2 Is Nothing
                    Loc2.Value = "Dog"
                    Set Loc2 = .FindNext(Loc2)
                Loop
            End If

        End With
        Set Loc = Nothing
        Set Loc1 = Nothing
        Set Loc2 = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```