# Error passing array to listbox as a parameter

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Objective : Create a userform and take a user input, and then from user input put it in a list and when you click the list it automatically find it in the whole workbook.

Something Like this:

[image]

I saw this post: [Match in whole workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba)

And I created something out of that:

```
Public Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim TempArray As Variant
    Dim RealArray()

    TempArray = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=64)
    ArrayRows = UBound(TempArray)
    ReDim RealArray(1 To ArrayRows)
    For i = 1 To ArrayRows
        RealArray(i) = TempArray(i, 1)
    Next i

    MsgBox "The number if rows selected are " & ArrayRows
    ListBox1.List = RealArray
    ListBox1 Arraay:=RealArray

End Sub

Public Sub ListBox1_Click(ByRef Arraay() As Variant)
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim something As Range
    Dim ArrayRows As Long

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With Sh.UsedRange
            For i = 1 To ArrayRows
                Set something = RealArray.Find(What:=RealArray(i))
                If Not something Is Nothing Then
                    Do Until something Is Nothing
                        test = something.Value
                        Set something = .FindNext(something)
                    Loop
                End If
            Next i
        End With
        Set something = Nothing

    Next
End Sub
```

After creating this, I get an error regarding the second sub.

> procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Comment: `Public Sub ListBox1_Click(ByRef Arraay() As Variant)` It doesn't take any parameters. It should be `ListBox1_Click()`

Comment: @SiddharthRout But how do I pass the array between sub? isn't that is one of the method? sorry, I'm quite new to VBA

Answer (score 1):

The Listbox click event doesn't take any parameters.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub
```

If you want to pass an array between sub then you can so it this way

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant

Public Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    '~~> Initialize array
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    '~~> Use array here
    '~~> Also put an error check if the array is initialized or not
End Sub
```