# Find Multiple Instances of Value in Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a macro in VBA that will search through a column in "PasteSheet" for any cell that contains the word "conversion". Once I have that cell, I can gather other information in other columns that correspond to that row. The problem I am encountering is creating some type of loop that will run through the entire database to return all instances of the word "conversion". Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim Comment As Range
Dim i As String

Worksheets("PasteSheet").Activate

Range("Comment").Find("conversion").Select


Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1") = Selection.Offset(0, -8)

End Sub
```

Help please!

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba#19509066) to learn how to perform multiple find searches. The inner If block in particular is what you need. Actually, [this Chip Pearson FindAll page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it. This will save the addresses of the found word in an array, and you can use that array however you like at the end.  I used column D as my example column. Change anything as necessary

```
Sub getCells()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim celAddress() As Variant
Dim i As Long
i = 0

Set rng = Range("D1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
ReDim cellAddress(rng.Cells.Count)

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = "conversion" Then
        cellAddress(i) = cel.Address
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cel

ReDim Preserve cellAddress(i - 1)

For i = LBound(cellAddress) To UBound(cellAddress)
    ' Do whatever with each cell address found
    Debug.Print cellAddress(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Couldn't find out how to make yours work, but it got me thinking in the right way to figure it out! Thank you!