# VBA to 'print' matched search results to new WS

Tags: vba, excel, loops, printf, match

I have some coding which loops through a list of policy numbers, and then searches through an entire workbook for a matching policy number, bolding any matches found in the original list. The coding works fine, however what I would like to do if possible, is to 'print' the address/cell location of the matching value. For example, if policy number 1 was located on sheet 3, cell a1, then this would be displayed on a new blank worksheet. I'm sure this can be done using dictionaries and the print.debug function, But I want to avoid using a dictionary if possible. Hope this makes sense!

```
 Sub HighlightMatches()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long,bln   As Boolean

 iRowL = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).row

 For iRow = 1 To iRowL

 If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 16)) Then
 For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            bln = False
            var = Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(16), 0)

            If Not IsError(var) Then
               bln = True
               Exit For
            End If
         Next iSheet
      End If


     ' The below would 'print' all matches and an offset value to a new Worksheet.
      If bln = False Then
         Cells(iRow, 16).Font.Bold = False
         Else
         Cells(iRow, 16).Font.Bold = True
      End If
   Next iRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: No need to loop. Simply use [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: An example from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightMatches()
Dim OriginalWS As Worksheet, NewListWorksheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Cel As Range, Rng As Range, rSearchCell As Range

Set OriginalWS = ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Columns("P:P").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

For Each Cel In Rng
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> OriginalWS.Name And ws.Name <> "Search List" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rSearchCell = ws.Columns("P:P").Find(What:=Cel.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rSearchCell Is Nothing Then
                Cel.Font.Bold = True
                Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Search List"
                On Error Resume Next
                Set NewListWorksheet = ActiveSheet
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not NewListWorksheet Is Nothing Then
                    NewListWorksheet.Range("A" & NewListWorksheet.Range("A" & NewListWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Cel.Value
                    Else
                    Set NewListWorksheet = Sheets.Add.Name = "Search List"
                    NewListWorksheet.Range("A1").Value = "Search results"
                    NewListWorksheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
                    NewListWorksheet.Range("A2").Value = Cel.Value
                End If
                Else
                Cel.Font.Bold = False
            End If
        End If
        Set rSearchCell = Nothing 'Clear Cel
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the quick response, however this doesn't seem to work. The coding doesn't launch a new worksheet called "Search List", I've also manually added one on but it doesn't make no difference. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, unfortunately I still cant get this to work, am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt555 what line is it crashing on?

Comment: It's not crashing as such, The macro runs but doesn't return any data or doesn't create a new worksheet. cheers