# VBA Concatenate Index/Match to Return Multiple Values

Tags: vba, excel

The code is a user-defined function that can be used in the worksheet. The function takes three arguments:

```
=MatchConcat(X1,X2,X3)
```

`X1` = The value you want to match

`X2` = The column of values that you want to match against, and

`X3` = The column of values that you want to return if there is a match.

It returns a comma-delimited string of the matched values.

Now, my concern is.... I was actually looking for an alternative and much better (performs faster) VBA function same as below. Currently this VBA function below is very helpful with my large set of data. Unfortunately, using this function to a thousands of rows or even hundreds take so long to load. It took 5 to 10 minutes (for a less than 1000 rows). I have already turned off the automatic formula calculation but still having the same issue.

```
Function MatchConcat(LookupValue, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range)
Dim lookArr()
Dim valArr()
Dim i As Long
lookArr = LookupRange
valArr = ValueRange
For i = 1 To UBound(lookArr)
    If Len(lookArr(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
        If lookArr(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
            MatchConcat = MatchConcat & ", " & valArr(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next
MatchConcat = Mid(MatchConcat, 3, Len(MatchConcat) - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post a code snippet of your attempt to resolve the problem?

Comment: This would probably be better suited to Code Review as the code works.  But, you'd be better using `FIND` rather than looking at each cell:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba).

Comment: Hard to believe your function takes 5-10 minutes for 1,000 rows.  Here it takes a fraction of a second.  Something else going on with your workbook or worksheet?