# VBA to copy over sporatic groups of rows to specific worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having issue getting this code to work. It should go through column A until it finds the next instance of "Employee", then copy those rows to a worksheet specified in column C, and then continue back down the list. I'm pretty new to VBA, could anyone help me out?

The employee information is in between each two instances of the word "Employee", so I've tried to set that as my trigger and my Start and End point for the rows.

Apologies everyone, as evident I am rather new. My goal with the code is to copy a range from one sheet ("Regs") to another sheet specified in a cell within said range on column C. This range is anywhere from 5 to 16 rows high, and each one is sandwiched by 2 instances of "Employee" in column A: one with "Employee: ###### - Lname, Fname" and one with "Employee Totals". My specific issues are with setting the loop to step a variable amount after copying each range (the variable amount being the # of rows of the previously copied range).

I have stumbled on a solution, which I put down below, but I am certain it could be done better.

```
Sub HourAllocationsRegs()

    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim strMyValue As String

    strMyValue = "Employee" 'Value to search for, change as required.
    Sheets("Regs").Select
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column A, change as required.

    For i = 2 To lRow Step K - i 'Starts on Row 7 and will jump to the next group according to row of next value
        StartRow = i
        For K = i + 1 To 100 Step 1
            If InStr(1, (Range("A" & i + 1).Value), strMyValue) > 0 Then
                EndRow = K
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Rows(Str(StartRow) & ":" & Str(EndRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Range("C" & Str(StartRow + 2)).Text).Select
        Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "I'm having issue getting this code to work" is not very helpful. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: can you clarify on the part `you want to copy those rows to a specified column into column C on a separate C`... you cant copy a row into a column unless you meant you want to copy a cell to that column...

Comment: You never set `K`'s value before the loop.  Therefore `For i = 2 To lRow Step K - i`  equates to   `For i = 2 To lRow Step 0 - 0` which means your loop will never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it without selecting the worksheets.

```
Sub HourAllocationsRegs2()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, x As Long, x1 As Long

    Dim SheetName As String, strMyValue As String
    strMyValue = "Employee"                           'Value to search for, change as required.
    With Worksheets("Regs")
        lngLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lngLastRow
            If InStr(1, .Cells(x, 1), strMyValue) > 0 Then
                For x1 = x + 1 To lngLastRow
                    If x1 = lngLastRow Or InStr(1, .Cells(x1 + 1, 1), strMyValue) > 0 Then
                        SheetName = .Cells(x + 1, 1).Value
                        .Rows(x & ":" & x1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        x = x1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much cleaner, I've marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to use Find.  If you have issues with find, you can use:

```
Dim i, j, k, LR as Integer
j=0
k=0
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to LR
    If Cells(i,1).Value="Employee" Then
        If k=0 And j=0 Then
            k=Cells(i,1).Row
        Else 
            If j=0 Then
                j=Cells(i,1).Row
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next i
DestinationRange.Value = Range(Rows(k+1),Rows(j-1)).Value 'Destination range is where you want to be; not defined
```

Comment: Assumes you only have the 2 instances of *Employee* so you are only recording 2 values indicative of the row they occur (j & k).  I didn't defined destination range, but put it in so the destination range values are the same as the j+1 to k-1 range.  Also made it do entire Rows, so you can always change Rows() to Cells() and correct the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the code Cyril! Unfortunately I have many instances of Employee (every contractor on site - if it didn't have their personal info I'd happily share XD), it's just that each "grouping" of employee info is between a cell value of "Employee - ###### Lname, Fname" and "Employee Totals". I did end up stumbling on a solution about 15 min ago, which I also posted.

Comment: @A.Giggey Copy; glad you found something! Was going to suggest a single storage using find, otherwise, similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few more hours on it and stumbled on a solution. Please edit if you can do it better!

```
Sub HourAllocationsRegs()

Dim strStartRow As String
Dim strEndRow As String
Dim strRefRow As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim strMyValue As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strMyValue = "Employee Totals" 'Value to search for, change as required.
Sheets("Regs").Select
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column A, change as required.

For i = 7 To lngLastRow Step (K - lngStartRow + 1) 'Starts on Row 7 and will jump to the next group according to row of next value
    strStartRow = (i + K - lngStartRow)
    strRefRow = (i + K - lngStartRow + 3)
    For K = Val(strStartRow) To lngLastRow Step 1
        If InStr(1, (Range("A" & K).Value), strMyValue) > 0 Then
            strEndRow = K
            Rows(strStartRow & ":" & strEndRow).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets(Range("C" & strRefRow).Text).Select
            Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Sheets("Regs").Select
            lngStartRow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```