# VBA Find a string and return row numbers of all results

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a code to extract all brand names from the cells with text structure similar to the text below:

```
….Brandname>Nekteck</span….
….Brandname>Dell</span….
….Brandname>Apple</span….
```

I used the Find property to find the text "Brandname>" to locate the row number and use InStr property to extract the brand name - the code is below. However, I need to find all brand names, not just the first one found. Any recommendation is appreciated.

```
Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Long
Dim closePos As Long
Dim Brand As String

Sheets("Workingsheet").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Brandname>", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Row = Brand1
str = Cells(Brand1, 2).Text
openPos = InStr(str, "Brandname>") + 10
closePos = InStr(str, "</span") - 7
Brand = Mid(str, openPos, closePos - openPos)
```

Comment: InStr has a "start from" argument, use that within a loop to find the next occurrence based on the position of the last one you found.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear enough. The occurrences are on a different cells on the sheet which are found by the Find property. Instr only works within one cell. I am looking for a way to find the rows of all these occurrences from the Find property. Thanks anyway Alex.

Comment: Ah, then you can loop calling .FindNext for the next match, E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba

Comment: Are you... parsing XML/HTML *by hand*? Is the input valid XML? If so, a simple XPath query could get you all your matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a loop like this one to find all matches:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set BrandName = .Cells.Find(What:="Brandname>")

If Not BrandName Is Nothing Then
 Do Until BrandName Is Nothing

  'add here you code (what you what to do when it finds it)

  Set BrandName = .FindNext(BrandName)
 Loop
End If

End With
```

Comment: I think this method do help me find the string I need. But my problem is how to record all the rows of the matches to use in the next steps. Is there anything I could add to this code to capture all the rows?

Comment: You can use BrandName.Row

Answer (score 0):

if you want to leave cells with brand names only, and these latter are in column A:

```
Sub LeaveBrands()
    With Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        .Replace "*Brandname>", "", lookat:=xlPart
        .Replace "</span*", "", lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

otherwise if you don't mind overwriting cells content and these latter are in column A:

```
Sub ListBrands()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        .Replace "*Brandname>", "", lookat:=xlPart
        .Replace "</span*", "", lookat:=xlPart
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            MsgBox cell.Value2
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```