# Speed up a VBA search in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following(see below) "File Search Utility" macro that I have been using in Excel 2010. This macro searches through a specified folder of workbooks and returns the desired data (love this macro!).

In Excel 2010, the search (which searches 450+ files) takes about 2 minutes and displays the results AS they are found.

In Excel 2016, the search takes more than double the time, and no results are displayed until the macro has completely run through all of the files in the folder.

I am a novice to intermediate macro programmer at best (i.e. I know enough to be dangerous). Any help to tweak this code would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub SearchButton_Click()
  Dim astrWorkbooks() As String
  Dim strPartNumber As String
  Dim strFolderPath As String
  Dim vntWorkbooks As Variant
  Dim j As Long
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  If Not ValidateData("PartNumber", strPartNumber) Then
    MsgBox "Part number has not been entered.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If Not ValidateData("SearchFolder", strFolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "Search folder has not been entered.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Call ClearResultsTable
  If Not FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "Search folder does not exist.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  vntWorkbooks = GetAllWorkbooks(strFolderPath)
  If IsEmpty(vntWorkbooks) Then
    MsgBox "Search folder does not contain any Excel workbooks.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  astrWorkbooks = vntWorkbooks
  For j = LBound(astrWorkbooks) To UBound(astrWorkbooks)
    Call SearchWorkbook(astrWorkbooks(j), strPartNumber)
  Next j
  MsgBox "Search has completed. Please check results table.", vbInformation
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub


Private Function FolderExists(ByRef strFolderPath As String) As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  If Right(strFolderPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
    strFolderPath = strFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator
  End If
  FolderExists = (Dir(strFolderPath, vbDirectory) <> "")
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  FolderExists = False
End Function


Private Sub ClearResultsTable()
  Dim tblResults As ListObject
  Dim objFilter As AutoFilter
  Dim rngBody As Range
  Set tblResults = wksSearchUtility.ListObjects("Results")
  Set objFilter = tblResults.AutoFilter
  Set rngBody = tblResults.DataBodyRange
  If Not objFilter Is Nothing Then
    If objFilter.FilterMode Then
      objFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
  End If
  If Not rngBody Is Nothing Then
    rngBody.Delete
  End If
End Sub


Private Function ValidateData(ByVal strRangeName As String, ByRef strData As String) As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  strData = UCase(Trim(wksSearchUtility.Range(strRangeName).Text))
  ValidateData = (strData <> vbNullString)
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  ValidateData = False
End Function


Private Function GetAllWorkbooks(strFolderPath As String) As Variant
  Dim lngWorkbookCount As Long
  Dim astrWorkbooks() As String
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim strFilePath As String
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  strFileName = Dir(strFolderPath & "*.xl*")
  Do Until (strFileName = vbNullString)
    lngWorkbookCount = lngWorkbookCount + 1
    strFilePath = strFolderPath & strFileName
    ReDim Preserve astrWorkbooks(1 To lngWorkbookCount)
    astrWorkbooks(lngWorkbookCount) = strFilePath
    strFileName = Dir()
  Loop
  If lngWorkbookCount > 0 Then
    GetAllWorkbooks = astrWorkbooks
  Else
    GetAllWorkbooks = Empty
  End If
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  GetAllWorkbooks = Empty
End Function


Private Sub SearchWorkbook(strFilePath As String, strPartNumber As String)
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim wbk As Workbook
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath, False)
  For Each sht In wbk.Worksheets
    Call SearchWorksheet(sht, strPartNumber)
  Next sht
ExitProc:
  On Error Resume Next
  wbk.Close False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  Resume ExitProc
End Sub


Private Sub SearchWorksheet(sht As Worksheet, strPartNumber As String)
  Dim rngTableRow As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  For Each cell In Intersect(sht.Columns("B"), sht.UsedRange).Cells
    If UCase(cell.Text) Like "*" & strPartNumber & "*" Then
      Set rngTableRow = GetNextRow()
      rngTableRow.Item(1).Value = sht.Parent.Name
      rngTableRow.Item(2).Value = cell.Text
      rngTableRow.Item(3).Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value
      rngTableRow.Item(4).Value = cell.Offset(, 6).Value
      rngTableRow.Item(5).Value = cell.Offset(, 7).Value
      rngTableRow.Item(6) = Range("I3")
    End If
  Next cell
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
End Sub


Private Function GetNextRow() As Range
  With wksSearchUtility.ListObjects("Results")
    If .InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
      Set GetNextRow = .ListRows.Add.Range
    Else
      Set GetNextRow = .InsertRowRange
    End If
  End With
End Function
```

Comment: This is some pretty well written code... one thing to address - the reason you're not seeing the sheets update is presumably because `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to false. This speeds up lots of macros dramatically but with the drawback that nothing is seen to change on a screen until it is complete

Comment: As for making this run more smoothly I would replace the `Like` function in `If UCase(cell.Text) Like "*" & strPartNumber & "*" Then` with `InStr()`. I'm not sure you'll even end up noticing much improvement, but it's a more "expensive" function to use given the application.

Comment: While I really like the line `For Each cell In Intersect(sht.Columns("B"), sht.UsedRange).Cells`, I'm not sure how its performance compares to the more well-known way of selecting the `LastRow` of a column using `.End(xlUp).Row`. So pending performance tests maybe that would be worth changing?

Comment: Also I'm not sure what `wksSearchUtility` is? It's not ever declared and it's used pretty often. Googling it gives no results, so I have to assume it's a personal variable here, so it might be helpful if it was defined. It's confusing that I can't find where it's declared because the code already includes `Option Explicit`... I must be missing something

Comment: I will admit, though, that I have no idea why changing from 2010 to 2016 cause such a dramatic time increase for you here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input Marcucciboy2. The bilk of this code was written for me so there is a lot of things going on that I am not even aware of (sadly). However, as I pick it apart and learn through these forums and the suggestions of generously willing persons like your self, I am getting a better understanding. Thank you so much for your input. You are the second person to ask me what wksSearchUtility is. I will ask the original writer for that info.

Comment: so instead of...

Comment: "For Each cell In Intersect(sht.Columns("B"), sht.UsedRange).Cells"... what would the Syntax look like using your suggestion?

Comment: It will take a little bit more than just changing that line, unfortunately. You'd have to make an extra `i` variable and do something like `For i = 1 to sht.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row` and then the times it references `cell` would end change to `sht.cells("B" & i)`

Comment: The biggest performance killer I see is actually opening the workbooks. Is this something you can do with an ADO connection?

Comment: Thank you all for your interest and input on this thread. Someone on another Forum re-wrote the code completely and the search now goes through 530 files in less than 5 seconds (was taking 4 minutes plus) I am posting it here for your enjoyment! thank you all so much, these forums are priceless to a learning novice like me.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oubx1bm6lfw25am/Invoice%20Search.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9g8kwnv5y2y6b1/VBA%20Code.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to include the solution mentioned by OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539783/speed-up-a-vba-search-in-excel-2016/52639064#comment92115656_52539783) as it is located on a different forum.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SearchButton_Click()

    Dim astrWorkbooks() As String, strPartNumber As String, strFolderPath As String, vntWorkbooks As Variant
    Dim j As Long, BlockSize As Long, myRng As Range, BigRng As Range, TempSht As Worksheet, i, myFormula As String, yyy As Range
    Dim Drng As Range, SceRng As Range, Destn As Range, msg As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Not ValidateData("PartNumber", strPartNumber) Then
        MsgBox "Part number has not been entered.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not ValidateData("SearchFolder", strFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "Search folder has not been entered.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call ClearResultsTable
    If Not FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "Search folder does not exist.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    vntWorkbooks = GetAllWorkbooks(strFolderPath)
    If IsEmpty(vntWorkbooks) Then
        MsgBox "Search folder does not contain any Excel workbooks.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set TempSht = Sheets.Add
    astrWorkbooks = vntWorkbooks
    BlockSize = 37

    For i = 1 To UBound(astrWorkbooks)
        myFormula = "='" & strFolderPath & "[" & astrWorkbooks(i) & "]Invoice'!R2C1:R" & BlockSize + 1 & "C9"
        Set myRng = TempSht.Range("B" & BlockSize * i - BlockSize + 1).Resize(BlockSize, 9)
        myRng.FormulaArray = myFormula
        myRng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 1).Value = astrWorkbooks(i)
        myFormula = "='" & strFolderPath & "[" & astrWorkbooks(i) & "]Invoice'!R3C9"
        myRng.Columns(myRng.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = myFormula
        If BigRng Is Nothing Then Set BigRng = myRng Else Set BigRng = Union(BigRng, myRng)
    Next i

    Set BigRng = BigRng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, BigRng.Columns.Count + 2)
    BigRng.Value = BigRng.Value

    With TempSht
        .Columns("D:H").Delete
        .Columns("C:C").Cut
        .Columns("B:B").Insert

        BigRng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*" & strPartNumber & "*"
        Set yyy = .AutoFilter.Range

        If yyy.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            Set Drng = .Range("A" & yyy.Rows.Count + 10)
            yyy.Offset(1).Resize(yyy.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Drng
            Set SceRng = Drng.CurrentRegion
            Set Destn = GetNextRow.Resize(SceRng.Rows.Count)
            Destn.Value = SceRng.Value
            msg = "Search has completed. Please check results table."
        Else
            msg = "Search has completed. No results found"
        End If

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False: .Delete: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation

End Sub

Private Function FolderExists(ByRef strFolderPath As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Right(strFolderPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        strFolderPath = strFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    FolderExists = (Dir(strFolderPath, vbDirectory) <> "")
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    FolderExists = False

End Function

Private Sub ClearResultsTable()

    Dim tblResults As ListObject
    Dim objFilter As AutoFilter
    Dim rngBody As Range

    Set tblResults = wksSearchUtility.ListObjects("Results")
    Set objFilter = tblResults.AutoFilter
    Set rngBody = tblResults.DataBodyRange

    If Not objFilter Is Nothing Then
        If objFilter.FilterMode Then
            objFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If

    If Not rngBody Is Nothing Then
        rngBody.Delete
    End If

End Sub

Private Function ValidateData(ByVal strRangeName As String, ByRef strData As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    strData = UCase(Trim(wksSearchUtility.Range(strRangeName).Text))
    ValidateData = (strData <> vbNullString)
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ValidateData = False

End Function

Private Function GetNextRow() As Range

    With wksSearchUtility.ListObjects("Results")
        If .InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
            Set GetNextRow = .ListRows.Add.Range
        Else
            Set GetNextRow = .InsertRowRange
        End If
    End With

End Function

Private Function GetAllWorkbooks(strFolderPath As String) As Variant

    Dim lngWorkbookCount As Long
    Dim astrWorkbooks() As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFilePath As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderPath & "*.xl*")

    Do Until (strFileName = vbNullString)
        lngWorkbookCount = lngWorkbookCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve astrWorkbooks(1 To lngWorkbookCount)
        astrWorkbooks(lngWorkbookCount) = strFileName
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop

    If lngWorkbookCount > 0 Then
        GetAllWorkbooks = astrWorkbooks
    Else
        GetAllWorkbooks = Empty
    End If
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    GetAllWorkbooks = Empty

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing every single cell in column B, that's the performance killer. Check this post for how to do this using the find function, it will be WAY faster.

[Find all matches in workbook using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba)

Where the code in that answer defines `loc`, replace `.cells` with `Intersect(sht.Columns("B"), sht.UsedRange)`

it should read something like this:

```
    Set Loc = Intersect(sht.Columns("B"), sht.UsedRange).Find(What:="Question?")
```

And obviously `"Question"` will become `strPartNumber`