# VBscript optimize Excel Search and Delete

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBScript function I was able to build that opens a excel file as specified by the user, and starts to parse Sheet 3's column C to see what the category is. If the category is not "Fruit" I want the entire row to be deleted. The function works as intended. However, I've noticed how extremely inefficient it is (takes roughly 3 seconds for 100 rows) and I need to be able to scan through nearly 11 000 rows. Is there a way I can optimize the search so that it takes just a few seconds to run through all the records?

```
   Function prepFile(usrFileSelected)
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(usrFileSelected)
        objExcel.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
        intRow = 2
        maxRow = objExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Do while intRow <= 1000
            currentValue = objExcel.Cells(3,intRow).value

            If currentValue <> "Fruit" then
                objExcel.Rows(intRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            intRow = intRow + 1 
        Loop
        msgbox("Done")
        objWorkbook.Save
        objWorkbook.Close
    End Function
```

Comment: That’s because Excel isn’t a database *(however many believe it to be)*. It’s always worth using the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be with [screen updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) disabled:

```
Sub prepFile(usrFileSelected)
    Dim Excel, Row

    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Excel.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Excel.Workbooks.Open(usrFileSelected)
        For Each Row In .Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows
            If Row.Cells(3).Value <> "Fruit" Then Row.EntireRow.Delete
        Next
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    Excel.Quit
End Sub
```

The next optimization idea would be to play with Excel's [`.Find` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba) to see if that is faster than the manual approach.