# VBA Excel Detect #REF! in the workbook and inform about it

Tags: excel, vba

Goood afternoon,

I would like to do the quick check of my workbook in order to detect potential #REF! values.

I found some good solution here:

[Find all matches in workbook using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba)

but when I apply it it changes all the values found.

I need something, which will inform me, that the unwanted value appear.

In this event I modified the following code:

```
 Sub FindAndExecute()

 Dim Sh As Worksheet
 Dim Loc As Range

 For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 With Sh.UsedRange
    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="#REF!")
    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            If Loc = True Then
            MsgBox ("Error found")
            End If
            'Loc.Value = "Answered!"
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
        Loop
    End If
   End With
   Set Loc = Nothing
 Next

End Sub
```

But I see no reaction. Is there any way to pop up the messagebox when the #REF value is found throughout the workbook?

Comment: Move the `MsgBox` before the `Do Until...`?

Comment: The only answer which worked for my by now is the FindLink option. All the codes below were not valid enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been using [FindLink](https://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm) from Bill Manville Associates for a long time now, and it has always been quite useful.

[image]

It gives warnings as you mean.
You can use it as it is. I am not sure you can access its code.

Comment: ++ Yes this is a good one which does comprehensive testing. `I am not sure you can access its code.` It is password protected which unfortunately doesn't hold any meaning in today's world. Hope they convert it to a VSTO Add-In.

Answer (score 4):

If a cell in Excel contains an formula with an error, it's content is not `#NAME?`or `#REF!` or something like that - this is only the way excel *displays* such errors. Therefore, searching for the string `#REF!` will not find anything.

There is an easy command that lets you find all cells containing errors - see the following code (assuming `sh` set to the sheet you want to look at)

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    Debug.Print cell.Address, cell.Formula
Next cell
```

**Update**: As BigBen points out, I was wrong with the text search for `#REF`, you can in fact use `Find` to find invalid references.

If your code doesn't find anything, maybe you have to provide the parameter `LookAt :=xlPart`.

The `Find`-method, however, will not find any other types of error like `#NAME?` or `#DIV/0`, while the `SpecialCells` will find all kind of errors in a real easy way.

**Update2** The following code will loop over all sheets and list all cells in error. I have also added some code to check if a sheet has any cell in error - if not, the `SpecialCells` will raise a runtime error - to avoid that I have put the statement into  a `On Error Resume Next`-statement.

```
Sub FindAndExecute()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim cell As Range, allCellsInError As Range
        Set allCellsInError = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set allCellsInError = Sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        On Error Goto 0
        If Not allCellsInError Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In allCellsInError
               Debug.Print Sh.Name; cell.Address; cell.Formula
            Next cell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "Therefore, searching for the string #REF! will not find anything" - not sure this is true. Just tested and searching for the string does find the error cell. The macro recorder produces the following code: `Cells.Find(What:="#REF!"....)`.

Comment: @BigBen: Your're right - that came as a surprise to me.

Comment: "The Find-method, however, will not find any other types of error like #NAME? or #DIV/0" doesn't seem correct either. In testing, if you look in values instead of formulas, seems like you can find them.

Comment: The option with LookAt works for me :) Now I am just wondering how to make the cell with error active.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Show the user the cell with error? Just `activate` the sheet and `select` the cell - but of course this makes sense only for one cell. If you have lots of cells with errors, you could use a conditional formatting rule and show them in an alarming red.

Comment: The code, which you presented above is not working. I am getting an error: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: is `sh` set (was assuming you are looping as in your original code) ?

Comment: If we are considering my original code, I don't know where should I place your code then.

Comment: Yes, I think now could be good. The error says: No error founds - debug/end. What will happen if error occur?

Comment: If you have "On Error Resume Next", the error msg "No errors found" is ignored (and not displayed) and execution is continued - a dangerous command that should only be used if you know what you are doing. In this case, variable `allCellsInError`  stay `Nothing` and the inner loop is not entered.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is actually about as efficient as can be, it just needs a couple of additions to show you where the errors were located.

```
 Sub FindAndExecute()

 Dim Sh As Worksheet, errorSheet As Worksheet
 Dim Loc As Range
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim lastFound As String

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 Set errorSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 errorSheet.Name = "Errors " & Format(Now(), "hh_mm_ss")
 i = 1
 
 For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 With Sh.UsedRange
    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="#REF!")
    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                errorSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Error on sheet " & Loc.Parent.Name & _
                    " in cell " & Replace(Loc.Address, "$", "")
               i = i + 1
               lastFound = Loc.Address
            End If
        Loop While Not Loc Is Nothing And lastFound <> Loc.Address
    End If
   End With
   Set Loc = Nothing
 Next

 If i = 1 Then errorSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "No errors were found"
 
End Sub
```

So first we [add a sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add) `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add` to hold the list of errors.

We use a counter `i As Integer` to keep track of the amount of errors found `If i = 1 Then errorSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "No errors were found"` and also to track the next free row on the error list `errorSheet.Cells(i, 1)`.

Lastly we use the [address property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) of the `Range` class to indicate which cell the `Find` method located: `Loc.Address`. I've used the [Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) to get rid of the absolute qualifiers `$` as the address property will prefix the cell and row with them e.g. $A$1.

Comment: Your code brings no reaction. Even if I put some different string than #REF!

Comment: I already spotted the #REF! error in my workbook. Unfortunately your code doesn't execute it.

Comment: My bad, I didn't test the code. Updated and tested now.

Comment: Now I am getting Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed

Comment: Sometimes it works fine, but creates additional 2 sheets at the end. One is Sheet 1 and another one is set in the code Errors and time like you stated.

Comment: I've already checked your code and even if some #REF! value in the cell appears somewhere in the document, the macro says that there is no errors.
Is there a possibility to make this code running? Does the sheet protection impacts on the code execution?

Answer (score 0):

> But I see no reaction. Is there any way to pop up the messagebox when the #REF value is found throughout the workbook?

Gives message boxes and selects/activates each Ref as it finds, and asks you on each if you wish to deal with.

When one of the cells in error is your specific value ("#REF!" in your case) then actives it.

See **version 2** below which is the better version (even if it does employ `goto` for the current processed refs)

```
 For Each cell In allCellsInError
          If cell.Text = "#REF!"
            Set myCell = cell
            Sh.Activate 'I think you can live without this.
            myCell.Select
```

Is the part the does it. When one of the cells in error is your specific value ("#REF!") then actives it.

Throughout the execution of code, when a particular value (Ref in your case) is found, its accompanied by a message box and question-answer choice if you want to deal with (which would effectively terminate the program and activate said cell containing that ref).

```
  Sub FindAndExecute11()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim myCell As Range 'this had to be declared to make the activations work (not for the loops ! which uses cell)
    
    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'I think you can remove this
    
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim x As Long
 
    
   refcount = 0
    
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim cell As Range, allCellsInError As Range
        Set allCellsInError = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set allCellsInError = Sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not allCellsInError Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In allCellsInError
            If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then ''only printong the refs (igniring all other errors)
            
            Set myCell = cell 'You need this for real time in the loop activations-selections of said cell
            
            Sh.Activate 'I think you can live without this.
            myCell.Select
            
            refcount = refcount + 1
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
             myArray(x) = Sh.Name & cell.Address
            x = x + 1
            
            
            
            MsgBox "Ref Found in " & cell.Address & " " & Sh.Name
               Debug.Print Sh.Name; cell.Address; cell.Formula
               
               answer = MsgBox("Do you want to go to cell" & cell.Address & " and fix?", vbYesNo)
                
                If answer = vbYes Then
                Sh.Activate
                cell.Select
                Exit Sub
                    Else
                  'MsgBox "No"
                End If 'must thank also -  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/ - for this
                
               
               End If
               
            Next cell
        End If
    Next
    
    
    
    
    'the following creates a new sheet after your sheets, and dumps contents of array (the Ref locations found) into it. It will only do this if all the Ref's are worked through and youve said "no" to dealing with them. In my 2nd version (to come) I will attempt to get a worksheet dump of all ref's no matter where you are in the procedure/process.


    
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
 Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
  'Range("A1:A" & UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray(x)
  
   For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(x)
'With sheet
'End With
  Next x
  
  With ActiveSheet
  For x = 1 To UBound(myArray)

  Cells(x, 1).Value = myArray(x)
 
  Next x
   End With
    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

More happy with the above code, working adapted from User @FunThomas' version.

But Here (below , **version 2**) is where I deal with the collection and print out of the REFs **UP TO THE POINT** you are in the execution of the program (so where you said yes, it stops code and prints out the found refs up to that point, If you never say yes, it will print out all the found refs when finished). With "dreaded" `goto` labels. (Its known that the COMMUNITY OF PROGRAMMERS say never use `GOTO` statements or logic. Using `GOTO` (or subroutines) they say it is a sign of ill-designed program and coding [I do not agree. not always.] - However I'm strapped for time). However-so, the only way *I* could get out the refs dealt with, in Output Worksheet to print , **WHILE YOUR IN THE MIDDLE OF YOUR PROCESS** ( message boxes) (so that **it also prints out the refs found up to that point**) was to use  `GOTO` in the code:

Also removed one of the message boxes in this version as it wasn't necessary, so you have only got one. I like this version better as it seems to do everything you & everyone wish.

**version 2:**  where all the action happens around/in/because of:

```
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to go to cell " & Sh.Name & cell.Address & " and fix?", vbYesNo)
```

`answer` variable defined previously as a `VbMsgBoxResult`

But both versions I have used a counter to count the specific refs and an `array` to store their positions (that way you can print out the array values as its doing in a final sheet) within the nested ifs in the for each sh loop.

```
           Sub FindAndExecuteVersion2() 
            Dim Sh As Worksheet
            Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
            Dim myCell As Range 'this had to be declared to make the activations work (not for the loops ! which uses cell)
            
            Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'I think you can remove this
            
            Dim myArray() As Variant
            Dim x As Long
         
            
           refcount = 0
            
            For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                Dim cell As Range, allCellsInError As Range
                Set allCellsInError = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set allCellsInError = Sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not allCellsInError Is Nothing Then
                    For Each cell In allCellsInError
                    If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then ''only printong the refs (igniring all other errors)
                    
                    Set myCell = cell 'You need this for real time in the loop activations-selections of said cell
                    
                    Sh.Activate 'I think you can live without this.
                    myCell.Select
                    
                    refcount = refcount + 1
                    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                     myArray(x) = Sh.Name & cell.Address
                    x = x + 1
                    
                   '' MsgBox "Ref Found in " & cell.Address & " " & Sh.Name
                       Debug.Print Sh.Name; cell.Address; cell.Formula
                       
                       answer = MsgBox("Do you want to go to cell " & Sh.Name & cell.Address & " and fix?", vbYesNo)
                        
                        If answer = vbYes Then
                        Sh.Activate
                        cell.Select
                        GoTo Line1
                        Exit Sub
                            Else
                          'MsgBox "No"
                          'GoTo Line1
                        End If 'must thank also -  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/ - for this
                        
                       
                       End If
                       
                    Next cell
                    
                End If
            Next
  
    
         Line1:

      'This section outputs the array of found refs upto the point you got to in the message boxes (either the whole thing if you say no to all, or from where you said ok yes deal with) on a sheet after all the other sheets. Basically its a screen dump of the console.
    
            
         Dim sheet As Worksheet
         Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
          
           For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            Debug.Print myArray(y)
    
          Next y
          
          With ActiveSheet
          For Z = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        
          Cells(Z, 1).Value = myArray(Z)
         
          Next Z
           End With
            
     End Sub
```

Comment: After dictionaries, Autofilter is the fastest search method. We could autofilter each sheet on a specific column. We'd need to use for each loop over last column range on each sheet to apply & iterate over each used columns on each sheet. I think. Idk. But would that be faster if you still have to iterate over used columns ?! Idk.  Look at autofilter method if that's something crazy you would consider implementing. Idk. Good luck !!

Answer (score -2):

I was bored, calmer (so much so!) and with time on my hands to do something useful/productive (which is what I live for, Cant function without trying to do something good at least). So I did something to improve my last code:

Changed the Array , (gosh its so nice to have some time & space without violent music from naighbours to be able to concentrate do something not in a hurry or trauma / anxiety *!) so that it functions properly. Gets the 1st element also (which was missing from the output sheet of the previous code) and also gets the current 'ref value position that the user stopped it for.

Pleased with this too much. ! :) If only I had this level of stress free non-anxiety yesterday. I can see much clearer. !!

Also added a segment in code at the start to un-hide any hidden columns that may be in the workbook sheets (as that is what the bounty winner's answer/tool does as well. The tool may not unhide them, but it can detect them even if they are in hidden columns. One way to do that with VBA is to vba-unhide those columns straight up ).

```
Sub FindAndExecuteVersion2()
            Dim Sh As Worksheet
            Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
            Dim myCell As Range 'this had to be declared to make the activations work (not for the loops ! which uses cell)
            
            Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'I think you can remove this
            
            Dim myArray() As Variant
            Dim x As Long
            
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Sh.Activate
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next
starting_ws.Activate
         
            
           refcount = 0
            
            For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                Dim cell As Range, allCellsInError As Range
                Set allCellsInError = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set allCellsInError = Sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not allCellsInError Is Nothing Then
                    For Each cell In allCellsInError
                    If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then ''only printong the refs (igniring all other errors)
                    
                    
                    Set myCell = cell 'You need this for real time in the loop activations-selections of said cell
                    
                    Sh.Activate 'I think you can live without this.
                    myCell.Select
                    
                    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                     myArray(x) = Sh.Name & cell.Address
                    'x = x + 1
                    refcount = refcount + 1 '' moved it up here 18/08/2020 20:15 (below to get the 1st. start from 0 . proper)
                    'x = x + 1
                    
                   '' MsgBox "Ref Found in " & cell.Address & " " & Sh.Name
                       Debug.Print Sh.Name; cell.Address; cell.Formula
                       
                       answer = MsgBox("Do you want to go to cell " & Sh.Name & cell.Address & " and fix?", vbYesNo)
                        
                        If answer = vbYes Then
                        
                        Sh.Activate
                        cell.Select
                        GoTo Line1
                        Exit Sub
                            Else
                          'MsgBox "No"
                          'GoTo Line1
                        End If 'must thank also -  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/ - for this
                        
                       x = x + 1
                       End If
                       
                    Next cell
                    
                End If
            Next
  
    
Line1:

      'This section outputs the array of found refs upto the point you got to in the message boxes (either the whole thing if you say no to all, or from where you said ok yes deal with) on a sheet after all the other sheets. Basically its a screen dump of the console.
    
            
         Dim sheet As Worksheet
         Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
          
           For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            Debug.Print myArray(y)
    
          Next y
          
          With ActiveSheet
          For Z = 1 To UBound(myArray) + 1 
        
          Cells(Z, 1).Value = myArray(Z - 1)  
         
          Next Z
           End With
            
     End Sub
```

Really pleased with this version.  * Maybe that's what liberals seek to do normalise - pass on to and in others.!?  Who knows?. It could be the only explanation for the mark down .

Comment: Code works well. I thought to say this again because reason 1. SO's own stated aims "useful code for people coming in the future to this page to know what works and what doesnt" . 2. there is code above (not mine) in this post which never worked & doesnt work - yet it got marked up, So im making this comment again for clarification for anyone that may come here in the future, my above code (which was marked down) works well & does the job the OP asked for. Other code here (marked up many times) doesnt work,(One for so-s own standards team to check?) or doesn't completely answer the question.

Answer (score -5):

This is the way I did it. I wouldn't have got anywhere close to this tonight, if it wasn't for mrfluff at MrExcel.

For references see [my question](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/whats-wrong-with-my-loop.1142653/) at Mr Excel I posted asking for help re:
looping over columns and rows of any particular sheet on an earlier version of the code I developed, which became "use the `usedrange`" courtesy of the excellent help I received from the wonderful @mrfluff over there.

Finds all refs and activates each as it goes and gives you the option on each found ref to stop the program and deal with it there and then in that cell. You can restart again after dealing.

```
    Sub FindRefsandErrorsinWorkbookBySheets24()
    Dim lastColumn As Integer

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim x As Long
   'Determine the data you want stored
  Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Resize Array prior to loading data
  'nope - ReDim myArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)
  
refcount = 0
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
'Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
       
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Activate
      For Each myCell In ws.UsedRange 'ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors) 'ws.UsedRange
         If myCell.Text = "#REF!" Then
         refcount = refcount + 1
         myCell.Select '' 1. COMMENT OUT FOR SPEED
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "This was a ref in " & myCell.Address
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
            myArray(x) = myCell.Address
            x = x + 1
            MsgBox "Ref Found in " & myCell.Address ''2. COMMENT OUT FOR SPEED
            If MsgBox("do you want to edit? - press cancel", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub ''3. COMMEMT OUT FOR SPEED
            
         ElseIf IsError(myCell.Value) Then
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Do you know you had different tyoe of error in " & myCell.Address & "???"
         End If
      Next myCell
      'MsgBox ws.Name
      
   Next ws
   
   MsgBox "Finished Checking. There where " & refcount & "ref errors! and they were in"
   
   Dim sheet As Worksheet
 Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
  'Range("A1:A" & UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray(x)
  
   For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(x)
'With sheet
'End With
  Next x
  
  With ActiveSheet
  For x = 1 To UBound(myArray)

  Cells(x, 1).Value = myArray(x)
 
  Next x
   End With
   
  ''Dim sheet As Worksheet
 ''Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
  'Range("A1:A" & UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray(x)
End Sub
```

It also finds all and each refs and gives you a list at the end where they are.

I've assumed you want them one by one and you can stop the macro at a particular one to fix it. But if you don't, comment out the entire 3 lines relating to message boxes, where I've written `COMMENT OUT THIS ENTIRE LINE IF YOU WANT SPEED .` Each one is '1, '2 and '3.

I had them in at the beginning, but once I was assured they worked, I removed them for speed of my testing, before putting them back in just now.

So those 3 sections each having a comment in themselves '1... '2... '3... comment out entirely those 3 lines and you've got a much faster macro with only a final message box with total number of refs, and the output of all the refs in immediate window and a new created sheet at the end.

I prefer the macro without those 3 lines inside, as it runs much more smoothly and quickly. But you were speculating at first if it would be good to edit-investigate the refs as you go/as you find them. So that's why I put them back in just now. But you can remove those 3 lines for a much faster less interrupted sub (& you get the array - total and print out of all the refs locations at the end anyway, so if I were you I'd live without those 3 lines).

Hope I helped. It worked for me. :)

Here is the macro (my preferred one, even if it doesn't show you the refs as it runs or gives you options to stop.) without the message boxes or activates  and without the pasting of offsets (which I only had in the 1st because I found them useful on development):

```
    Sub FindRefsandErrorsinWorkbookBySheets245()
        Dim lastColumn As Integer
    
        Dim myCell As Range
        Dim LastRow As Long
        
        Dim myArray() As Variant
        Dim x As Long
       'Determine the data you want stored
      Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    'Resize Array prior to loading data
      'nope - ReDim myArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)
      
    refcount = 0
    Dim ws As Worksheet
           
       For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          ws.Activate
          For Each myCell In ws.UsedRange 'ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors) 'ws.UsedRange
             If myCell.Text = "#REF!" Then
             refcount = refcount + 1
            ' myCell.Select '' 1. COMMENT OUT FOR SPEED
              '  myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "This was a ref in " & myCell.Address
                ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                myArray(x) = myCell.Address(, , , 1) '' THIS GETS YOU THE SPECIFICS (SHEET NUMBER TOO)
                x = x + 1
              '  MsgBox "Ref Found in " & myCell.Address ''2. COMMENT OUT FOR SPEED
              '  If MsgBox("do you want to edit? - press cancel", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub ''3. COMMEMT OUT FOR SPEED
                
        '     ElseIf IsError(myCell.Value) Then
         '       myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Do you know you had different tyoe of error in " & myCell.Address & "???"
            End If
          Next myCell
      
          
       Next ws
       
       MsgBox "Finished Checking. There where " & refcount & "ref errors! and they were in"
       
       Dim sheet As Worksheet

     Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    
      
       For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(x)

      Next x
      
      With ActiveSheet
      For x = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    
      Cells(x, 1).Value = myArray(x)
        
      Next x
       End With
     
    End Sub
```

They are identical. The only difference is `'` lines which changes behaviour.

It just occurred to me (your language phrase: detect them and activate the cells, **Where they appear `(optionally one by one)`**  Its got me thinking, how would could you have the option to activate cell without knowing where the option is visibaly other than a list given to you or message box (i.e how could you be given option to activate or not without seeing it?)

But strictly going by your words alone, I re-wrote the original macro (which has those unneccissary and potentialy data overwriting offsets) to do that exactly.

The ref is informed to you by a message box, and then a 2nd message box asks if you wish to deal with that Ref (with address) or continue. Yes would select the cell and end the macro/sub. No would just continue.

SO This one is not activating any cell or any worksheet until you decide. You get your messages one by one per ref, and any message box with a  particular ref your interested in, is the one you decide to activate-select that ref cell and deal with or not. slightly different. The sheet and cell is only 'activate' (selected) and the program stopped, when you decide based on being told by msgbox (I guess you have a good mental map of where these cells are in your sheets, and you already know which one is more important!?).

With thanks to a [go to guy (Jon) at  excelcampus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCh7ki9yVsM) and the people at automateexcel [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/)

This one works also. All 3 do, slightly differently, depending on how you read your words.

```
Sub FindRefsandErrorsinWorkbookBySheets26()
        Dim lastColumn As Integer
    
        Dim myCell As Range
        Dim LastRow As Long
        
        Dim myArray() As Variant
        Dim x As Long
        
        'excel campus - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCh7ki9yVsM
        Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
        
       'Determine the data you want stored
      Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    'Resize Array prior to loading data
      'nope - ReDim myArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)
      
    refcount = 0
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    'Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
           
       For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          ''' ws.Activate 'you could comment this out too if you dont need or want to see the sheets, and put it back in the "yes portion" of "i wasnt to deal with" - as you kinda implied you want to be chooser of what ref to activate
          For Each myCell In ws.UsedRange 'ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors) 'ws.UsedRange
             If myCell.Text = "#REF!" Then
             refcount = refcount + 1
             '''''myCell.Select '' deleted because your wording kind of suggests you want to choose when to select/activate the cell.
                myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "This was a ref in " & myCell.Address
                ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                myArray(x) = myCell.Address
                x = x + 1
                MsgBox "Ref Found in " & myCell.Address ''2. COMMENT OUT FOR SPEED
                ''''If MsgBox("do you want to edit? - press cancel", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub ''3. COMMEMT OUT FOR SPEED
                
           Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to go to cell" & myCell.Address & " and fix?", vbYesNo)
                
                If Answer = vbYes Then
                ws.activate
                myCell.Select
                Exit Sub
                    Else
                  'MsgBox "No"
                End If 'must thank also -  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/ - for this
                
             ElseIf IsError(myCell.Value) Then
                myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Do you know you had different type of error in " & myCell.Address & "???"
             End If
          Next myCell
          'MsgBox ws.Name
          
       Next ws

       If refcount = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Finished Checking. There were " & refcount & " Ref Errors!"
       Exit Sub
       End If

       
       MsgBox "Finished Checking. There where " & refcount & "ref errors! and they were in"
       
       Dim sheet As Worksheet
     Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
      'Range("A1:A" & UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray(x)
      
       For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(x)
    'With sheet
    'End With
      Next x
      
      With ActiveSheet
      For x = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    
      Cells(x, 1).Value = myArray(x)
     
      Next x
       End With
       
      ''Dim sheet As Worksheet
     ''Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
      'Range("A1:A" & UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray(x)
    End Sub
```

Quickest/simplest way imo to handle the last or only potential error in this code and terminate cleanly (that is, if `myarray` was empty or it found no refs) and account for empty myarray/null array, no ref error situation, was to `If refcount = 0 Then` otherwise determining if the array was isempty(myarray) = true  proved to be a little too difficult extra work & complicated at his time.

Comment: Thank you Martijn . SIncerely mean it, Much respect & thanks to you Sir ! "edits/history of posts are viewable by others" - I never noticed that before. Thank you for taking the time to edit so well.