# Excel VBA Find all cells containing text (partial match) and return entire row

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy-paste

I have a large table on 'Sheet1' with thousands of rows and multiple columns.

I'd like to include a search function (similar to Excel's built in find all search that goes through the entire 'Sheet1' and returns all rows where a partial match was found (in any column).

I then want all these rows to be copied to another sheet in the document. There's already some data there in the first few rows (including the search box).

[I'm using cyberponks find all function (see below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55349092) but clearly have no idea how to use it properly

```
Function FindAll(rng As Range, What As Variant, Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByColumns, Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, Optional MatchByte As Boolean = False, Optional SearchFormat As Boolean = False) As Range
Dim SearchResult As Range
Dim firstMatch As String
With rng
    Set SearchResult = .Find(What, , LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
    If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
        firstMatch = SearchResult.Address
        Do
            If FindAll Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = SearchResult
            Else
                Set FindAll = Union(FindAll, SearchResult)
            End If
            Set SearchResult = .FindNext(SearchResult)
        Loop While Not SearchResult Is Nothing And SearchResult.Address <> firstMatch
    End If
End With
End Function
```

This is the code I've come up with so far

```
Sub Search_Button1_Click()

Dim FindWhat As String
Dim foundCells As Range
Set lblActiveX = Sheet2.Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object
FindWhat = lblActiveX.Object.Value
Set foundCells = FindAll(Sheet1.UsedRange, FindWhat) 
        If foundCells Is Nothing Then
            Msgbox ("Value Not Found")
        Else
            For Each cell In foundCells
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B9" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this is

1. It doesn't return partial matches
2. If a search word is found multiple times within a row, it copies the same row as many times as the word appears.

I need to be able to search in every column, but I only need the row once if any match is found.

I do have a unique ID column  "A" but not sure if I should use that to return each row only once.

3. Have absolutely no clue as to how I can find matches if more words are entered.

So for instance if the following three words are entered "anxiety depression free" I would like the row to be returned that contains "depression" in column "B" , "anxiety" in column "C" and "free" in column D. None of these words would appear only on their own, but inside a sentence or part of a list separated by commas. Their order varies as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The [XlLookAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat) parameter can be set to `xlPart` to get partial matches

2.Assuming the cells in the range that is returned from `Findall()` is in the same order as the cells in the range that was passed as the `rng` parameter to `Findall()`, when you iterate through each cell in `foundCells`, store the `cell.row` into some variable `lastfoundrow`. Then for the next `cell` only copy that row if `cell.row <> lastfoundrow`:

```
'init as zero so it will not match cell.row the first time (row cannot be 0)
lastfoundrow = 0

For Each cell In foundCells
    If cell.row <> lastfoundrow then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B9" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        ' only store *after* we have compared cell.row to lastfoundrow above
        lastfoundrow = cell.row
    End If
Next
```

Then it should skip that cell if it is in the same row as the last found cell.

3.Not sure I understand this one.

Comment: Thanks garbb for your quick answer. I'm afraid I need some more help regarding the actual syntax of your answer to question 2. I do understand your logic, but every time I try I seem to set "lastfoundrow" to be equal to the current row. Do you think you can help me? Question 3 is about essentially being able to search for multiple words separately and then return only the rows in which every keyword appears at least once.. Hope that makes more sense. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Sorry my explanation of the lastfoundrow was not very good. I have edited my answer to improve it.

Comment: How are the search words being input? All together into textbox1 separated by spaces like this "word1 word2 word3"? If so, then first you need to [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) them into separate strings. Also I think that what you want would require quite a bit different code... You would need to look at each row, then for each row check if it matches all of your words, then if so copy that row.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I haven't yet fully tested it (I'm having a few other annoying issues), but it sure looks like it solves my biggest headache, so thank you. Regarding question 3, yes, your totally right that's exactly what I'm after, and yes it requires a different approach, even more so because what I eventually want is to load the results into a listbox on a userform instead of writing them to a sheet. But I'll leave that one for later, because I certainly don't know excel enough to even begin writing that code. It was a long shot. Anyway, thanks again, so I marked my question answered.