Move Non-adjacent columns to adjacent rows in VBA
I'm trying to move some non-adjacent columns of data and transpose to adjacent rows in another tab. I'm doing this using the below For Each loop but it's breaking on the second iteration for "Runtime Error 1004: Select method of Range class failed" at c.select. Why?
I got FindAll() from here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx
Sub move_scores_to_final()
'
' move_scores_to_final Macro
'

'
    Sheets("analysis worksheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Dim Rng7 As Range
    Set Rng7 = FindAll(Range("1:1"), "Adjusted Score", xlValues, xlPart, , True)
    
    Rng7.Select
    
    Dim c As Range, sel As Range, i As Integer
    i = 1
    Set sel = Selection
    
    For Each c In sel.Cells
        c.Select
        c.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("final worksheet").Select
        Range("A1").Offset(i, 12).Select 'this is to make the rows adjacent and i need to put the data starting in column 12
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        i = i + 1
    Next c

End Sub

I'm trying to move the yellow columns

to transpose to the rows starting at M2


You can't select a cell on a non-active sheet...

Please share the code of FindAll().

Please edit your question to show sample data using markdown table so we can reproduce your problem. You should be able to do this without using vba.

Maybe like this:
Sub move_scores_to_final()

    Dim Rng7 As Range, wsAnalysis As Worksheet, wsFinal As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    
    Set wsAnalysis = Worksheets("analysis worksheet")
    Set wsFinal = Worksheets("final worksheet")
    
    Set Rng7 = FindAll(wsAnalysis.Rows(1), "Adjusted Score", xlValues, xlPart, , True)
    
    i = 1
    For Each c In Rng7.Cells
        wsAnalysis.Range(c.Offset(1), wsAnalysis.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
        
        wsFinal.Range("M1").Offset(i).PasteSpecial _
                 Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        i = i + 1
    Next c

End Sub

...assuming FindAll is a function which returns a Range; something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55349092/478884

thanks, i did something similar to this and it worked. do you have thoughts on why the OP code was failing? here's my final code: https://imgur.com/a/8lqT3i7

I commented below your post on the problem with your code


Copy values without using PasteSpecial

Sub move_scores_to_final()
    Dim oShtFinal As Worksheet, oShtAna As Worksheet
    Set oShtFinal = Sheets("final worksheet")
    Set oShtAna = Sheets("analysis worksheet")
    Dim Rng7 As Range
    Set Rng7 = FindAll(oShtAna.Range("1:1"), "Adjusted Score", xlValues, xlPart, , True)
    If Not Rng7 Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Range, i As Long
        i = 1
        For Each c In Rng7.Cells
            With oShtAna.Range(c.Offset(1), oShtAna.Cells(oShtAna.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp))
                oShtFinal.Cells(i, 12).Resize(1, .Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Next c
    End If
End Sub


If you have 365, you can do this with a worksheet function in a single cell. The results will SPILL to the adjacent cells.
Adjust the data range to some reasonable size that is larger than your data. The algorithm finds the columns that contain the value Adjusted Score in row 1, and then transposes each of those columns
=LET(
    data, Sheet2!A1:ZZ1000,
    _C1, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Adjusted Score", INDEX(data, 1, 0))) * COLUMN(data),
    colNums, FILTER(_C1, _C1 <> 0),
    xpose, HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSECOLS(IF(data = "", "", data), colNums))),
    xpose
)

Small Example

To do the same thing but using a VBA macro, you can try:
Option Explicit
Sub nonAdjColsToRows()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDest As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vDest As Variant
    Dim cols As Object
    Dim V, I As Long, J As Long, numRows As Long, numCols As Long
    
'Naming a specific workbook would be more robust
'  But need more information to properly define this
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Add destination worksheet if it doesn't exist
On Error Resume Next
Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Cleaned Data")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets.Add
            wsDest.Name = "Cleaned Data"
        Case Is <> 0
            MsgBox "Error adding worksheet" & vbLf & Err.Description & "Error Number: " & Err.Number
    End Select
On Error GoTo 0
Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(1, 1) 'Initially set to A1, but set wherever you want first cell to be
    
'Get range to search
'Code assumes first cell is `A1`
' and column names are in row 1
' if there is other data on the worksheet, will need a different method
    V = LastRC(wsSrc.Name)
        numRows = V(0)
        numCols = V(1)
    
    With wsSrc
        Set rSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(numRows, numCols))
        vSrc = rSrc
    End With
    
'Columns to transpose
    Set cols = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        cols.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
            If vSrc(1, I) Like "Adjusted Score*" Then cols.Add Item:=.Transpose(.Index(vSrc, 0, I)), Key:=vSrc(1, I)
        Next I
    End With

'Size destination array
    ReDim vDest(1 To cols.Count, 1 To numRows)
    
'populate destination array
    I = 0
    For Each V In cols.keys
        I = I + 1
        For J = 1 To UBound(vDest, 2)
            vDest(I, J) = cols(V)(J)
        Next J
    Next V
 
'write to the worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clear the destination range
'then populate and format it
Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vDest, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vDest, 2))
With rDest
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vDest
    .ColumnWidth = 255
    .Style = "Output" 'may not work in non-English environment
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub

'find the last row and column being used on a worksheet
'returns a two element array with those values
'enter either worksheet as a string, or range as a range object
Function LastRC(SheetOrRange) As Long()

'Uncomment next line if being used on worksheet
    Application.Volatile 'else it won't update when changes made
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, s(1) As Long
    
Select Case TypeName(SheetOrRange)
    Case "Range"
        Set r = SheetOrRange
    Case "String"
        Set r = Worksheets(SheetOrRange).Cells
    Case Else
        MsgBox "unexpected error"
        Exit Function
End Select
    
    
With r
    Set c = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        s(0) = c.Row
        Set c = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        s(1) = c.Column
        LastRC = s
    Else
        LastRC = Array(xlErrValue, xlErrValue)
    End If
End With

End Function


this is awesome! but i'm trying to use a vba macro so it's automatic as i'll have to do this many times in the same type of workbook

@imrobert What do you mean? Do you mean you have many different data sources? Many different workbooks? Something else? If you have the same range but are editing the data table, this will update dynamically.

i have a teammate who downloads a workbook with raw data regularly and manually washes it, so i'm writing this macro to do it for him

@imrobert He's going to either have to copy the macro to the workbook; edit the macro to reference the desired workbook; have the macro available as an add-in; or copy the formula to the workbook. In any event, I've provided VBA code that can do the same as the formula. As written, it will refer to the Active Workbook, but should be modified so you can refer to a particular workbook by name. Please read the code comments and ask if you don't understand something. Most work is done in VBA arrays, as referencing and writing to/from the worksheet is less efficient.
